# element-wise order implies norm order?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb R^n$. If $0\le v_1 \le v_2$ element-wise, is it true that $\|v_1\| \le \|v_2\|$ for any norm $\|\cdot \|$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For example $$||(x,y)||=|x|+|x-y|$$is a norm on $\Bbb R^2$ for which this is false (consider $v_1=(2,0)$, $v_2=(3,3)$).